# sort django queryset using a temporary field which is not listed in model

Tags: python, django

My model is as follows:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.charfield(max_length = 200)
    surname = models.charfield(max_length = 200)
```

In my function:

```
people_list = People.objects.all()
for each in people_list:
    if some_conditions:
        each.level = 1
    else:
        each.level = 2
```

I need to sort the people_list using level variable I've added.
I get `FieldError` when trying to do

```
people_list = people_list.order_by('level')
```

Comment: If the `some_conditions` is "simple" it can be encoded in the query... But that depends on the `some_conditions`...

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the extra field with conditional value and order using that field.
Here's an example.

`People.objects.annotate(level=Case(When(condition,then=Value(1)),default=Value(2),output_field=IntegerField())).order_by('level')`

Doc related to When Case,
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

Comment: Ashin : I did not wanted to change the question, so I've created a new question based on your inputs. please check this question too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71237880/unable-to-use-case-when-then-in-django-queryset

Comment: I have replied to your question.